# Read an image from pod library

Tags: ios, swift3

In my pods, I have downloaded a library.And that library has under it resources - > assets.bundle--> list of images. Am trying to access one of my libraries like below, but I keep getting fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value. How to solve?

```
        let imageView = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: "sa"))
        imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentMode.center
        imageView.frame = CGRect(x:0.0, y:0.0, width:imageView.image!.size.width + 20.0, height: imageView.image!.size.height)
```

Comment: Am trying to access one of my libraries like below -> you mean you trying to access one of your libraries 's image ?

Comment: yes, its this library. https://github.com/mustafaibrahim989/MICountryPicker am trying to access the flag icons of  a country . its under micountrypicker->resources->assets.bundle

Comment: in which line you face this issue

Comment: @krikorHerlopian pls check if  `let imageView = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: "Frameworks/MICountryPicker.framework/assets.bundle/sa"))` work for you.
If it works i will convert this to an answer!

Comment: @krikorHerlopian pls accept my answer. :)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of :

```
    let imageView = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: "sa"))
```

you can get image from pod libs like bellow:

```
let imageView = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: "Frameworks/MICountryPicker.framework/assets.bundle/sa"))
```